# SqlException was not Handle by user code ....Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

i got error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); other part work correct but in this part having error when i updating record in gridview 
`connectionString cs= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AddUserConnectionString"].ConnectionString;` .....it works properly but not update record in database,show this error..

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox CName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CName") as TextBox;
        TextBox CNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CNumber") as TextBox;
        TextBox CAltNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CAltNumber") as TextBox;
        DropDownList PlanType = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_PlanType") as DropDownList;
        TextBox WNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_WNumber") as TextBox;
        TextBox CAddress = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CAddress") as TextBox;
        TextBox Date = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Date") as TextBox;



        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cd,con);
        cmd.Connection = con;

         cmd.CommandText = "Update CustomerDetails set( CName='" + CName.Text + "',CNumber='" + CNumber.Text + "',CAltNumber='" + CAltNumber.Text + "',PlanType='" + PlanType.SelectedItem+ "',WNumber='" + WNumber.Text + "',CAddress='" + CAddress.Text + "',Date='" + Date.Text + "') where CNumber='" + CNumber.Text + "'";

         int abc=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        if ( abc != 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Details Submitted...";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Details Not Submitted...";
        }
        con.Close();

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        ShowData();
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be bracketing your assignments. `set cname=...`, not `set (cname=...`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update CustomerDetails set( CName='" + CName.Text + "',CNumber='" + CNumber.Text + "',CAltNumber='" + CAltNumber.Text + "',PlanType='" + PlanType.SelectedItem+ "',WNumber='" + WNumber.Text + "',CAddress='" + CAddress.Text + "',Date='" + Date.Text + "') where CNumber='" + CNumber.Text + "'";
```

The `'('` within your update statement wirght after `set` is wrong. You must remove the matching `')'` before the where as well.
Plaease use parameters.

Comment: This is actually a more correct answer than the one I wrote below since it focuses on the error.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be more clear if you clean up your query a little bit:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox CName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CName") as TextBox;
            TextBox CNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CNumber") as TextBox;
            TextBox CAltNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CAltNumber") as TextBox;
            DropDownList PlanType = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_PlanType") as DropDownList;
            TextBox WNumber = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_WNumber") as TextBox;
            TextBox CAddress = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_CAddress") as TextBox;
            TextBox Date = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Date") as TextBox;



            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cd,con);
            cmd.Connection = con;

             cmd.CommandText = "Update CustomerDetails set
CName=@cName, 
CNumber=@cNumber, 
CAltNumber=@cAltNumber,
PlanType=planType, 
WNumber=@wNumber,
CAddress=@cAddress, 
Date=@date
where CNumber=cNumber";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cName", CName.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cNumber", CNumber.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cAltNumber", CAltNumber.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@planType", PlanType.SelectedItem));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@wNumber", WNumber.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cAddress", CAddress.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", Date.Text));


             int abc=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
            if ( abc != 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Details Submitted...";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Details Not Submitted...";
            }
            con.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            ShowData();
        }
```

Complete syntax here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp¨

Note that I also put the values as parameters, which (in my opinion) will make the query more clear, but also prevent [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It's drawn by hand, but I hope it will help you on the way.